# Java classloader: difference between defining loader & initiating loader?

Tags: java, classloader

From [JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> A class loader L may create C by defining it directly or by delegating
>   to another class loader. If L creates C directly, we say that L
>   defines C or, equivalently, that L is the *defining loader* of C.
>
> When one class loader delegates to another class loader, the loader
>   that initiates the loading is not necessarily the same loader that
>   completes the loading and defines the class. If L creates C, either by
>   defining it directly or by delegation, we say that L initiates loading
>   of C or, equivalently, that L is an *initiating loader* of C.

I am a little confused about those.

Suppose we have two class loaders: L and L<sub>p</sub>, and L<sub>p</sub> is parent of L.

If C is defined in L and successfully created by L, then L is both *defining loader* and *initiating loader* of C, is that correct?

If C is defined in L but created by L<sub>p</sub>, I guess L<sub>p</sub> is *initiating loader* of C?
 
but what is C's *defining loader*? since C is defined in L but not directly created by it? that's a problem.

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classloaders usually follow a delegation mechanism.
Suppose the delegation hierarchy is `L->Lp->Lq` and the class is defined in `Lp`
In this case, 
`L` will delegate the class loading to `Lp`,
`Lp` will delegate to `Lq`
`Lq` will not load the class and the call returns back to `Lp`. 
`Lp` will load the class since it is defined in `Lp` and the call returns back to `L`.
Here `Lp` and `L` are the initiating class loaders and `Lp` is the defining class loader.
Similarly if the delegation heirarchy is `L->Lp` and the class is defined in `L`,
 `L` becomes the defining and initiating class loader. 
`Lp` is not the initiating class loader.
Simply put, if the class loader is able to return a reference to the *Class* instance in the delegation chain, it is an initiating class loader.